# I want to run .ipynb file in batch script

Tags: python, batch-file, ipython

I have a .ipynb file named "prod.ipynb" i  want to run it in a batch script and i want to schedule it in task scheduler. I installed Anaconda, and when i was trying to run it by converting to python, some tensorflow errors were coming and i can't install .dll files due to company restrictions. I wrote a small python code which will help me run the .ipynb files, it will convert the .ipynb to .py and run it but the script is only working when im running it from anaconda prompt. What i want to do is, i want to write a batch script which will open anaconda prompt and then it will run my python script.

```
start activate root c:\Anaconda3\python.exe c:\Users\foo\Desktop\runner.py "c:\users\foo\prod.ipynb"
```

When im running above script, anaconda prompt opens up.

```
(base) C:\Anaconda3\Scripts>
```

What i wanted to do is, i want to open anaconda prompt and run this particular script,

```
c:\Anaconda3\python.exe c:\Users\foo\Desktop\runner.py "c:\users\foo\prod.ipynb"re
```

and i want to do it in batch script.

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't, like almost every other example already on this site, be using `call` instead of `start`?

Comment: `CALL Activate Root` should be on it's own line.  `Python.exe` should be on its own line with its parameters.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by using 'CALL' method.
what i have done is, i wrote a batch script, below is the code

```
call c:\anaconda3\scripts\activate root
runipy "C:\users\foo\Prod.ipynb"
```